# How to efficiently update such a directed graph?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have many nodes. The definition of a `Node` is like this:

```
public class Node
{
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   string Expression { get; set; }
   double Value { get; private set; }
}
```

The `Value` is evaluated by an expression evaluation engine at runtime. The `Expression` can reference other `Node`s, so it can form a directed graph (or a list of directed graphs). Assume there are no cycles in the graph.

Here is an example:

```
NodeA:
{
    Name: "NodeA",
    Expression: "[NodeB] + [NodeC] + 1.0"
    Value: 4.0
} 

NodeB:
{
    Name: "NodeB",
    Expression: "1.5"
    Value: 1.5
} 

NodeC:
{
    Name: "NodeC",
    Expression: "2.0"
    Value: 2.0
}
```

The question is if the NodeB is changed, how to propagate the changes to other nodes efficiently? Can I use some parallel method to update the graph?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would want to propagate the changes. When you evaluate the expression in Node A, won't that fetch the latest value for Node B and Node C?

Comment: Sorry, I just mean how to update the whole graph. Yes I can use BFS to evaluate the dependent nodes serially. I want to know if there is a parallel method to update the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have each node maintain a list of dependent nodes and also a "dirty" flag. Then whenever a node changes, recursively set the dirty flag on every dependent node. (If a node is already marked dirty, don't recurse.) You can then make a second pass to re-evaluate each dirty node, clearing the dirty flag as its new value is calculated.

Comment: Thanks. This method is similar to what I'm doing now. First, I use BFS mark all the dependent nodes as dirty, then I evaluate all the dirty nodes. Can I improve this algorithm using parallel updates?

Comment: @Johnsonlu - I'm not sure. Perhaps [this MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569760.aspx) on paralellizing operations with dependencies might offer some ideas.

Comment: Thanks:) This link is very inspiring.